# Tensorflow: Error when using placeholder for `pool_size` arguments

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to pool images to reduce their resolution. I want the pooling size as well as the strides to be dynamic. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The `pool_size` argument must be a tuple of 2 integers.
Received: [<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>] including element
Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", dtype=int32) of type <class 
'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

Somehow, using

```
px_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
py_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
```

to pass the pooling size and strides to my function results in an error. But why does it not work?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

in_width, in_height = 10, 10
R = np.random.rand(10000, in_width, in_height)
px, py = 5,5

def my_pool(R, px, py):
    # Reshape [N,W,H,C]
    X = tf.reshape(R, [tf.shape(R)[0], tf.shape(R)[1], tf.shape(R)[2], 1])
    # Pooling
    return tf.layers.average_pooling2d(X, pool_size=[px,py], strides=[px,py], padding="same", data_format='channels_last')

R_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, in_width, in_height])
px_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
py_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

pooling = my_pool(R_, px_, py_)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(pooling, feed_dict={R_:R, px_:px, py_:py}).shape)
```

Comment: Your line: `return tf.layers.average_pooling2d(X, pool_size=[px,py], strides=[px,py], padding="same", data_format='channels_last')` passes in pool_size as a list, not a tuple.  Maybe this function is super picky?  Replacing with `return tf.layers.average_pooling2d(X, pool_size=(px,py), strides=[px,py], padding="same", data_format='channels_last')` would fix what I'm thinking about

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I had for ideas.  I would suggest changing it in your presented code so others don't think the same as me.

Comment: This is impossible, pool and stride params must be known in advance to create an operation. What are you trying to do? I never heard about anything like that. Maybe you just need global average pooling?